# Trouble changing textView background inside a filtered listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview

I'm trying to change the background of a textView inside of a listView.  The textView is how the list is displayed.  This works correctly before I introduced filtering, then the background seemed to get attached to the original position.  So if the filter was removed the background change would stay at the position.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    //view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.DarkGrey);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    RssItem rss = (RssItem) parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(rss.getLink()));
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

That is my onItemClick.  The view.setBackgroundResource was the original call to change the color which works without a filter.

Comment: Where does the error occur.  Be more specific.  Why is the first line commented out?

Comment: What's the xml use are using to set the row?